# How to select multiple tables?

Tags: mysql

```
country | total users count | active users count | inactive users count | discipline subscribers count | top discipline | study level subscribers count | top study level
```

table countries

```
country_id | short_name
```

table user  (if status = 2 active if status = 1 inactive)

```
id | country_id | status
```

table user_subscribed_disciplines

```
id | user_id |discipline_id
```

table announcement_disciplin

```
id | name
```

table user_subscribed_study_levels

```
id | user_id | study_level_id
```

table cat_study_levels

```
id | name
```

answer must be like this

```
country | total users count | active users count | inactive users count | discipline subscribers count | top discipline | study level subscribers count | top study level
USA     |       506         |          500       |     6                |    50                        |          PHD   |          90                   |  Social History
CAN     |       406         |          406       |     0                |    50                        |          POS   |          0                   |  Social History
```

Comment: You should show what you have done so far. Stackoverflow is not a coding service.

Comment: do the table have a relationship between each other? what have you tried so far?

Comment: SELECT countries.short_name, COUNT(user.id), COUNT(user.status) FROM user RIGHT JOIN countries ON user.country_id = countries.country_id
GROUP BY short_name
HAVING COUNT(user.status) = 2

Comment: Please edit your original post with this information, the comment boxes are not meant for this. Please read the information about how to ask a good question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
SELECT countries.short_name,
       COUNT(user.id),
       COUNT(user.status)
FROM `user` RIGHT JOIN countries
            ON `user`.country_id = countries.country_id
GROUP BY short_name
HAVING COUNT(`user`.status) = 2
```

Comment: Whot is error in this case SELECT countries.short_name, COUNT(user.id), COUNT(user.status) FROM user RIGHT JOIN countries ON user.country_id = countries.country_id
GROUP BY short_name
HAVING COUNT(user.status) = 2

Comment: it's not working. If status = 0  don't see Countries

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a conditional statement, like the following. Do not forget to put "``" to your "user" table.

`` SELECT countries.short_name, COUNT(user.id), SUM(case when `user`.status = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as variablename FROM `user` RIGHT JOIN countries ON `user`.country_id = countries.country_id GROUP BY short_name; ``