# How to select multiple tables? with 6 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a 6 tables

table countries

`country_id | short_name`

table user  (if status = 2 active if status = 1 inactive)

 `id | country_id | status`

table user_subscribed_disciplines

    `id | user_id |discipline_id`

table disciplin

  `id | name`

table user_subscribed_study_levels

`id | user_id | study_level_id`

table study_levels

    `id | name`

How to select all countries with his parameters? How to write right sql query?

```
   country | total users count | active users count | inactive users count | discipline subscribers count | top discipline | study level subscribers count | top study level
   USA     |       506         |          500       |     6                |    50                        |          PHD   |          90                   |  Social History
   CAN     |       406         |          406       |     0                |    50                        |          POS   |          0                   |  Social History
```

Comment: A sample of the table data and the SQL you have coded so far would help.

Comment: This is a fairly straight-forward join... The number of tables doesn't make it any more complex than a simple two-table join.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I join multiple SQL tables using the IDs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9853586/how-can-i-join-multiple-sql-tables-using-the-ids)

Comment: I have already replied to the same question you asked today. Take a look.

Comment: As @MiguelH stated, try to give an example of what you have tried. You can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) how to do that.

Comment: SELECT countries.short_name, COUNT(user.id) FROM user RIGHT JOIN countries ON user.country_id = countries.country_id
GROUP BY short_name                                   after that I can do nothing

Comment: Duplicate(?) of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49668038/how-to-select-multiple-tables/49672306#49672306, In fact... it is a duplicate created by the same user...

Comment: Have you even tried anything????  Where's your query????  Have you tried to Google it???  There are tons of example online.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a query like below I think:

```
select c.country_id
     , count(u.id) as TotalUsers
     , sum(case when u.status = 'active' then 1 else 0 end) as ActiveUsers
     , sum(case when u.status = 'Inactive' then 1 else 0 end) as InactiveUsers
     , (select count(*) from user_subscribed_disciplines) as DisciplineSubscribers
     , (select name from (select top 1 name,count(*) from disciplines group by name order by count(*) desc) t) as TopDiscipline
     , (select count*) from  user_subscribed_study_levels) as StudyLevelCount
     , (select name from (select top 1 name,count(*) from study_levels group by name order by count(*) desc) t) as TopStudyLevel
from countries c
inner join user u on u.country_id=c.country_id
```